# How to grep download speed from wget output?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, wget

I need to download several files with `wget` and measure download speed.

e.g. I download with

```
wget -O /dev/null http://ftp.bit.nl/pub/OpenBSD/4.7/i386/floppy47.fs http://ftp.bit.nl/pub/OpenBSD/4.7/i386/floppyB47.fs
```

and the output is

```
--2010-10-11 18:56:00--  http://ftp.bit.nl/pub/OpenBSD/4.7/i386/floppy47.fs
Resolving ftp.bit.nl... 213.136.12.213, 2001:7b8:3:37:20e:cff:fe4d:69ac
Connecting to ftp.bit.nl|213.136.12.213|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1474560 (1.4M) [text/plain]
Saving to: `/dev/null'

100%[==============================================================>] 1,474,560    481K/s   in 3.0s

2010-10-11 18:56:03 (481 KB/s) - `/dev/null' saved [1474560/1474560]

--2010-10-11 18:56:03--  http://ftp.bit.nl/pub/OpenBSD/4.7/i386/floppyB47.fs
Reusing existing connection to ftp.bit.nl:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1474560 (1.4M) [text/plain]
Saving to: `/dev/null'

100%[==============================================================>] 1,474,560    499K/s   in 2.9s

2010-10-11 18:56:06 (499 KB/s) - `/dev/null' saved [1474560/1474560]

FINISHED --2010-10-11 18:56:06--
Downloaded: 2 files, 2.8M in 5.9s (490 KB/s)
```

I need to grep the total download speed, that is, the string `490 KB/s`.
How do I do this?

P.S. May need to account for the case that we will actually download only one file, so there won't be final output starting with `FINISHED`

Comment: `wget 'https://x.com' -O /dev/null  2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<= \()\d+\.?\d+ \SB/s(?=\) )'` explanation, save to null, reroute err to out, output matching only, use hardcore regex, positive lookbehind, positive lookahead

Answer (score 4):

Update, a grep-style version using sed:

```
wget ... 2>&1 | sed -n '$,$s/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/p'
```

Old version:

I thought, it's easier to divide the file size by the download time after the download. ;-)

```
(/usr/bin/time -p wget ... 2>&1 >/dev/null; ls -l newfile) | \
awk '
   NR==1 {t=$2};
   NR==4 {printf("rate=%f bytes/second\n", $5/t)}
'
```

The first awk line stores the elapsed real time of "real xx.xx" in variabe `t`. The second awk line divides the file size (column 5 of `ls -l`) by the time and outputs this as the rate.

Comment: Not easier, it seems to me. I have to determine both file size and the download time, divide, and what if time equals zero? Please provide the example how to do it e.g. with bash

Comment: Reported time zero needs special attention. It seems grepping is perhaps easier. Somehow I had the dynamical and progressive output of wget in mind which I thought hard to grep.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, using your `wget -O /dev/null <resource>`

The regex I used was `\([0-9.]\+ [KM]B/s\)`

But note I had to redirect `stderr` onto `stdout` so the command was:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://example.com/index.html 2>&1 | grep '\([0-9.]\+ [KM]B/s\)'
```

This allows things like `923 KB/s` and `1.4 MB/s`

---

`grep` just finds matches. To get the value(s) you can use `sed` instead:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://example.com/index.html 2>&1 |
    sed -e 's|^.*(\([0-9.]\+ [KM]B/s\)).*$|\1|'
```

Comment: For me, it returns the whole line that contains the speed. But how do I get only what's inside the brackets? e.g. `923 KB/s` or `1.4 MB/s`?

Comment: Now, the example with `sed` does work - it extracts the speed (`923 KB/s`), but before that it prints out all the other output as well.

Comment: @Nick: combine them. Unix shell is all about pipelining - `wget abc | grep ghi | sed xyz`

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov You can pass the `--only-matching` (`-o`) option to grep to get the just the string inside the brackets.

Comment: ... im sure there is reason to the insanity. why stderr. oh well.

Answer (score 2):

**This works when only 1 file is being downloaded.**

I started using `sed` to get the speed from wget, but I found it irritating so I switched to grep.

This is my command:

```
wget ... 2>&1 | grep -o "[0-9.]\+ [KM]*B/s"
```

The `-o` option means it only returns that part. It matches 1 or more of the 10 digits then a space. Then optionally `K` or `M` before the `B/s`

That will return `423 KB/s` (for example).

To grep for just the units, use `grep -o "[KM]*B/s"` and for just the number use `grep -o "[0123456789]\+`.

Comment: I would remove the star from the second character class, you only need exactly one K or M. Also note that there are several occurances of speeds in the output, not all of which are of interest to the OP; a complete solution needs to take context into account, which afaik cannot be done by a single `grep call`.

Comment: That only gave 1 output for me... :/  He's got multiple ones but he said that he wouldn't have 2 files...? I was only using 1 file.

Answer (score 0):

For example, get speed in MBit per second (by adding --report-speed=bits for wget, and small change grep pattern):

```
wget -O /dev/null --report-speed=bits http://www.ovh.net/files/10Mb.dat 2>&1 | grep -o "[0-9.,]\+ [KM]*[Bb]/s"
```

answer:

```
1,51 Mb/s
```

Comment: This may not cover the speed in Gbps. Please increase the coverage.

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you just do this:

```
perl -ne "/^Downloaded.*?\((.*?)\)/; print $1"
```

Comment: The line with "Downloaded" might not be there, if only one file was fetched.

Comment: How do I use this thing together with wget?

Answer (score -3):

here's suggestion. You can make use of `wget's` `--limit-rate=amount`  option. For example,

`--limit-rate=400k` will limit the retrieval rate to 400KB/s. Then its easier for you to 
calculate the total speed. Saves you time and mental anguish trying to regex it.