# scripting with sed and wget in Windows

Tags: sed, wget

I have some issue with Internet connectivity in a LAN. Some users are happy and some complain about the Internet speed.  So I came with an idea to install software on three different PCs and try to download/upload a file at the same time and record the speed. Then I will able to create a graph with the data that I acquired.

I am looking for a way to download several files and check the speed. I found [How to grep download speed from wget output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909128/how-to-grep-download-speed-from-wget-output) for wget and sed. How do I use `wget -O /dev/null http://example.com/index.html 2>&1 | sed -e 's|^.*(\([0-9.]\+ [KM]B/s\)).*$|\1|'` for Windows? I already installed `wget` and `sed` on Windows.

All PCs running Windows XP or 7.

Comment: Why not use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)?

Comment: did you try `tracert` from the 3 separate PCs? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Sed isn't different on Windows. The only difference is, that /dev/null doesn't exist on Windows, but NUL.

So:

```
wget -O NUL http://example.com/index.html 2>&1 | sed -e 's|^.*(\([0-9.]\+ [KM]B/s\)).*$|\1|'
```

should work on Windows. I'm not 100% sure about 2>&1 - maybe there is some other syntax to use.