# Wget option to output last line to the file on openWRT

Tags: linux, wget, openwrt

I want to output only the last line of wget in to the File.
I am using openWRT with `wget-nossl` package

when I am trying to output all the file with `wget 2>tempLOG` command:
my router get very slow internet connection.(it cuts speed 3 times because it writes to the file).
so I would like to write to the file only the last line of the `wget` command which prints:
x MB downloaded in Y time.

is there any option to do so ?

Comment: Could you please add punctuation to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to grep download speed from wget output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909128/how-to-grep-download-speed-from-wget-output)

One of the solution :
wget -O /dev/null your_url 2>&1 | grep '([0-9.]+ [KM]B/s)'